# SinonStub function observer

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, chai, sinon

I try to test express middleware through sinon.js

I wanna test, that it send to response specific JSON and don't let request go to next middleware or request handler.

```html
const middleware = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  setTimeout(() => res.json({status: 'blocked'}), 1000);
}
```

For mocking Request and Response I use `sinon-express-mock`. So every property and method in Response object is `SinonStub`

My problem is, that when I call middleware and method `json` is called, I don't know, how to check it, after it's called.

Is there some listener or Observer on SinonStub?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the unit test solution:

`index.ts`:

```js
import { NextFunction, Response, Request } from 'express';

const middleware = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  setTimeout(() => res.json({ status: 'blocked' }), 1000);
};

export { middleware };
```

`index.test.ts`:

```js
import { middleware } from './';
import { Request } from 'express';
import sinon, { SinonFakeTimers } from 'sinon';

describe('56676480', () => {
  let clock: SinonFakeTimers;
  before(() => {
    clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
  });
  after(() => {
    clock.restore();
  });
  it('should pass', () => {
    const mReq = {} as Request;
    const mRes = { json: sinon.stub() } as any;
    const mNext = sinon.stub();
    middleware(mReq, mRes, mNext);
    clock.tick(1000);
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(mRes.json, { status: 'blocked' });
  });
});
```

unit test results with 100% coverage:

```sh
  56676480
    ✓ should pass


  1 passing (12ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.ts |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```